# Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) being called multiple times in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

In my application i'm defining a class which implements ihttpmodule and it contains following methods

```
  public void Init(HttpApplication application)
    {
        application.EndRequest += new EventHandler(Application_EndRequest);
    }


 private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;


        IObjectContainer objectClient = context.Items[KEY_DB4O_CLIENT] as IObjectContainer;

        if (objectClient != null)
        {
            objectClient.Close();
        }

        objectClient = null;
        context.Items[KEY_DB4O_CLIENT] = null;
    }
```

when i try to run the application and debug it, i notice one strange thing:

in chrome private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) is getting executed 3 times when the application starts and again 3 times when the application ends.

in Internet explorer private void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) is getting executed 2 times when the application starts and again 2 times when the application ends.

Why is Application_EndRequest getting executed multiple times. Is it not supposed to run only once ?

And also i would like to know the difference between Visual Studio Development Web Server and IIS ?

What is the difference between both of me.

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I am seeing the same thing, did you ever figure out why? I'm hitting the site using `curl` so I doubt there's anything else going on.

Answer (score 12):

`Application_EndRequest()` will be called as many times as there are requests handled by the runtime. With the VSDev Server, that will be -every- request; including ones for images, and other various resources the browser might look for... such as a bookmark icon image.

That could also explain the difference between the browsers; IE and Chrome may have differences in what extra things they are trying to request, particularly re: the site icon.

Comment: @Andrew is it a overhead to add Application_EndRequest and Init methods in application as they have to get executed multiple times before every request ? And is there a explicit way to call them only once when the application starts and ends ?

Comment: Do you mean `Application_Start` and `Application_End`, maybe?

Comment: @Andrew it seems like they get executed when there is no need for them to get executed ? Why do they get executed like that ?

Comment: No, they are called exactly when they are supposed to be... at the end of every *Request*... that's why it is called "EndRequest". What you want is `Application_End`... not `Application_EndRequest`.

Comment: @Andrew i will try and comeback to you.

Comment: @Andrew there is no change even if i change from Application_EndRequest to Application_End still it is displaying the same behaviour. I don't understand it !!